# validation rule unique in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I want to do a validation of two fields, I have tried but it does not work for me, exactly what I need is for two fields to be validated.

what I want is that the namames of fields "grado" and "fk_nivel_academico" are not repeated

This is the table in my database:

```
-----------------------------------------------
id | grado    | fk_nivel_academico | fk_estado
1  | Primero  | 1                  | 1
2  | Segundo  | 1                  | 2
```

This is the validation rule:

```
$validatedData = Validator::make(
       [
           'grado' => $this->grado
       ],
       [
           'grado' => [
               'required', 
               Rule::unique('grado')
                   ->where('fk_nivel_academico', '==', $this->fk_nivel_academico)
                   ->where('grado', '==', $this->grado)
               ]
       ],
```

Comment: `==` isn't the equal operator in terms of sql ... you can also remove the second where since that is what the rule will do already ... and your table is named `grado`?

Comment: This is enough `Rule::unique('grado')
                   ->where('fk_nivel_academico', $this->fk_nivel_academico)
                   ->where('grado', $this->grado)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem it's that you are using the `==` comparator when in sql it is `=`.
The other solution I would recommend you to use, is to make a `Rule` file.
Here's a guide [How to create custom validation](https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-custom-validation-rules-laravel/)

And in the passes method you could use something like this

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
   $table = Table::where('fk_nivel_academico', '=', $this->fk_nivel_academico)
   ->where('grado', '=', $this->grado)->get();

   if($table->count() == 0){
        return true;
   }
}
```